# How to convert Pandas dataframe column into bin string data?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, bins

I have a Pandas dataframe called odf that looks like this:

```
Customer         Employees
   A                 2
   B                 100
   C                 5
   D                 1000
```

I have created custom bins for the employee data:

```
df = odf['Employees']
bins = [0,5,1000]
df.value_counts(bins=bins)

(-0.001, 5.0]        2
(5.0,   1000]        2
Name:Employees, dtype: int64
```

now I'd like to 'join' this data but am unsure how to do this, or if there is an easier way to accomplish what I need.  I want the end result to look like this:

```
  Customer         Employees    NewBinColumn
   A                 2          -0.001, 5.0
   B                 100         5.0,   1000
   C                 5          -0.001, 5.0
   D                 1000        5.0,   1000
```

That way I can see the bin column next to the original dataframe columns

here is what I tried that did not work:

```
ndf = odf.join(df, lsuffix='Employees', rsuffix='Employees', how='left')
ndf
```

And while it does join the two, what I get is this:

```
  Customer         EmployeesEmployees    Employees
   A                 2                     2
   B                 100                   100
   C                 5                     5
   D                 1000                  1000
```

If this was SQL I'd use a case statement to get the new column, but I was hoping there is an easier way to dynamically do this without writing out a really long statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly the same formating that what you want, but using [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) on `odf['Employees']` such as:

```
odf['NewBinColumn'] = pd.cut(odf['Employees'],bins)
```

will give:

```
  Customer  Employees NewBinColumn
0        A          2       (0, 5]
1        B        100    (5, 1000]
2        C          5       (0, 5]
3        D       1000    (5, 1000]
```

Comment: This is close enough.  I'm newb enough to handle the formatting after the fact.  I just tend to make things more complicated than need be. Thanks again.